# How can I remove this toilet shutoff valve?

Tags: plumbing, toilet

This valve has a slow leak, and I am trying to replace it.  Problem is I can't get the thing off.  I am trying to twist the compression nut (the bronze one closest to the white pipe) clockwise while holding the valve in place.  Am I doing this wrong?

Here's a picture of the valve:
[image]

Comment: When you replace the valve, I'd highly recommend replacing it with a quarter-turn ball valve. They're slightly more expensive, but much easier to shut-off (and when you need to shut off a toilet, you *NEED* to shut off a toilet) and *way* more reliable long-term.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think that is a compression fitting, it looks more like the valve is threaded. Have you tried just turning the valve (silver in color) and not the brass fitting (which is probably soldered onto the pipe)?

Comment: I agree, it looks like threads covered in dope.  Try holding the copper/brass piece stationary, while turning the valve body anticlockwise (Lefty Loosey).

Comment: first time I have heard the term anti-clockwise. I'd only ever heard/used counter-clockwise before. Wikipedia says its a commonwealth English term (counter is North American).  I learn something every day :)

Comment: Thanks.  I will try this out a little bit later on today.

Comment: @ Steven, at least anti-clockwise is intuitive. What if he used widdershins? Or for tightening, deasil. Scottish origins I believe :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments and answers. It looks like the valve should thread off the brass but, if that doesn't work for you try this. Unscrew the crome cap (packing nut) and unscrew the valve all the way out. Inside there will be a hard rubber seat. It's usually held in with a Philips screw. Whatever joinery method, bring it to your local hardware store and replace the seat. Reassemble. Test.

This is what the seat may look like. 
 [image]
www.pinterest.com